# Turn off display (MHS-3.5inch) on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am currently experimenting with the MHS-3.5inch display (http://www.lcdwiki.com/MHS-3.5inch_RPi_Display) and a Raspberry Pi 4.

So far everything is working fine. But now I want to turn off the display somehow! The Pi should be running but the display should be black without any backlight..

Is there any way to do this?

Thx